# using <#include> resoults in error: Can't find resource

Tags: freemarker

I am implementing a freemarker code in an environment that stores the templates in an database.
for example

```
${bundle.key}
```

will display the value of the row with row_id = 'key'
However when I use include directive something doesn't work.
I have a template with a key GenF as follows

```
<#function PriceFormat Number>
 <#return Number?string['0.0000']>
</#function>
```

if i run

```
   ${GenF.PriceFormat(1.568)}
```

I get the output

```
   1.5680
```

as expected.
but when i run

```
<#include bundle.GenF>
${PriceFormat(1.568)}
```

I receive an error message:

```
Can't find resource for bundle ...structures.shared.localization.bl.MultiResourceBundle, key
```

do I use the include directive wrong, or is something was not defined correctly in the Data model by our programmers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include` expects the *name* 
(path, "file" name) of a template, not the template content itself. See: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html

What you seem to want is `<@bundle.GenF?interpret />`. Though note that the parsed template won't be cached that way, unlike when you invoke a template with `#include`. For `#include` to be able to resolve "bundle.GenF" as template name (or rather something like `"bundle:/GenF"`, but it's up to you), you have to use a custom `TemplateLoader` (see `Configuration.setTemplateLoader`).

As far as you only need this for defining custom number formats, you may also want to consider using custom number formats (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html), like `${1.538?string.@bundle_GenF}`.